# Определение ссылок селекторами CSS

Tags: css-selectors, css

Возможно ли задать определенные свойства css только тем ссылкам, которые ведут на просторы вне сайта? Есть селектор:

```
a[href^="http"] { ... }
```

...но это вообще для всех ссылок. По идее хотел, чтобы выглядело как-то так:

```
a:not[href^="http://имя_сайта"] { ... }
```

Но это не работает, видимо, :not нельзя использовать таким образом. Возможно ли это вообще реализовать на чистом CSS? (на javascript я и сам умею)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

нормально not работает. Вы его не туда поставили =)

```
a[href^="http"]:not([href*="mysite.com"]) {
    /* some css */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3D9Wk/

Answer (score 1):

Пишешь селектор для всех ссылок и селектор для внутренних ссылок. В первом указываешь свойства нужные для всех ссылок на сайте и специфичные для внешних ссылок, во втором сбрасываешь свойства специфичные для внешних ссылок.

Но выборка по значению атрибута это всё-таки довольно дорого, лучше добавлять на внешние ссылки какой-то класс и мачиться по нему.